# How to operate datetimes in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have this code:

```
! wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqfxvfz2y2e74il/Online%20Retail.xlsx
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
from datetime import datetime
df_retail = pd.read_excel('Online Retail.xlsx',parse_dates=True)
df_retail2 = df_retail.dropna()
df_retail3 = df_retail2.loc[df_retail2['Quantity'] > 0]
df_retail3['año-mes'] = pd.to_datetime(df_retail3['InvoiceDate'])   #############
df_retail3
```

The content of `df_retail3['InvoiceDate']` is:

```
0        2010-12-01 08:26:00
1        2010-12-01 08:26:00
2        2010-12-01 08:26:00
3        2010-12-01 08:26:00
4        2010-12-01 08:26:00
             ...        
541904   2011-12-09 12:50:00
541905   2011-12-09 12:50:00
541906   2011-12-09 12:50:00
541907   2011-12-09 12:50:00
541908   2011-12-09 12:50:00
```

I want that this line:

```
df_retail3['año-mes'] = pd.to_datetime(df_retail3['InvoiceDate'])
```

add only the year and the month to the new column 'año-mes' to get in that column:

```
        2010-12
        2010-12
        2010-12
        2010-12
        2010-12
             ...        
        2011-12
        2011-12
        2011-12
        2011-12
        2011-12
```

My try was:

```
df_retail3['año-mes'] = pd.to_datetime(df_retail3['InvoiceDate']).datetime.strptime(aa, '%Y-%m')
```

But it does not work, the error says:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

**What do you suggest me to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try doesn't work for sure because to_datetime is only a valid attribute to Pandas module.  That's why it returns "Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime"

You cannot use datetime that way.  Your code needs to be something like this to work.

```
df_retail3['año-mes'] = pd.to_datetime(df_retail3['InvoiceDate']).dt.to_period('M')
```

Comment: `df_retail3['InvoiceDate'].dt.to_period('M')`  it worked, thank you !!!!